# MS-DOS: Why some people still programming in DOS today?

Tags: windows, operating-system, dos

I have just a curiousity: Why some people still programming in MS-DOS??? I have read the Flat Assembler forum, and they have a section for DOS programming. I have looked in the internet, and it has many programming tutorials and many people working today in the old DOS. Why???

Comment: This is not the type of question this site is for. It is for solving practical programming problems, not asking why people choose particular operating systems.

Comment: @RaymondChen Do you know a place where I can put this type of questions?? I know that this question do not match with the spirit of this site, but I do not know where I can get answers to my questions. Please, don't downvote me. I can be blocked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An embedded- or industrial control system which boots to DOS can have a much shorter start-up time than one which boots to Windows.  If a machine exists for the sole purpose of running one particular program, and if it will need a file system but won't need many of the other features that an OS like Windows would provide, using DOS may be easier than trying to get something set up on "bare metal".

The increasing availability of free or inexpensive file-system drivers which can communicate with USB sticks or SD cards, and the increasing popularity of ARM-based controllers, does reduce the attractiveness of DOS-based embedded-systems for new designs, but if a DOS-based machine works, and there's no anticipated need for functionality beyond what DOS would be able to provide, maintaining it may be easier than trying to design around something else, especially if it includes hardware for which Windows drivers have never existed.

BTW, the television show "How It's Made" has a segment talking about piano rolls; it shows a piano-roll company's puncher being operated by an Apple ][+.  Since segment was shot in high-def video, that clearly suggests that the Apple ][+ was being used well into the twenty-first century even though the Apple ][+ was already obsolete by the mid 1980s.  On the other hand, if the company bought up a reasonable supply of spare parts when other companies were unloading obsolete Apple ][-based equipment, then as long as someone can be found who remembers how the Apple ][ worked, there may be little or no advantage to switching to something more "modern".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clarifies the why some people still using MS-DOS. Do you know if MS-DOS can have Internet??? Or in other case, Do you know where I can post this type of answers???

Comment: @Martin: DOS itself does not provide any of the logic that is necessary for a device to do things like determine its IP address or do any of the other prerequisites for Internet communication.  It is, however, possible to load device drivers to accomplish such things or to have an application explicitly exchange network packets with other devices for such purpose.  For devices with sufficiently-simple networking requirements, having applications implement the networking logic themselves may reduce the risk of security holes if they ignore anything they're not particularly expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know where I can find tutorial about how to write DOS drivers for beginners???

Comment: If you know x86 assembly language, I would suggest you look up how to implement a TSR (Terminate and Stay Resident) program using interrupt 27h; while it's possible to implement a TSR as an EXE file, it's simplest if you can do it as a header-less COM file.  That's the approach I took on the one DOS-based embedded system I designed.  A device driver can do a few things a TSR cannot, but implementing a TSR is probably easier.